# Fixing a for loop in Genie

Tags: python, vala, genie

I would like to make a simple password check routine in Genie, however I got stuck in a for loop. Here is the python code I want to mimic:

```
#-----------------------------------------------
# password_test.py
#    example of if/else, lists, assignments,raw_input,
#    comments and evaluations
#-----------------------------------------------
# Assign the users and passwords
users = ['Fred','John','Steve','Ann','Mary']
passwords = ['access','dog','12345','kids','qwerty']
#-----------------------------------------------
# Get username and password
usrname = raw_input('Enter your username => ')
pwd = raw_input('Enter your password => ')
#-----------------------------------------------
# Check to see if user is in the list
if usrname in users:
    position = users.index(usrname) #Get the position in the list of the users
    if pwd == passwords[position]: #Find the password at position
        print 'Hi there, %s. Access granted.' % usrname
    else:
        print 'Password incorrect. Access denied.'
else:
    print "Sorry...I don't recognize you. Access denied."
```

Here is as far I could get:

```
[indent=4]

init
    users: array of string = {"Fred","John","Steve","Ann","Mary"}
    passwords: array of string = {"access","dog","12345","kids","qwerty"}

    print "Enter user name"
    var usrname = stdin.read_line()
    print "Enter password"
    var pwd = stdin.read_line()

    var position = 1
    var i = 1
    for i=0 to i < users.length
        if (users[i]==usrname)
            position += 1
            if pwd == passwords[position]
                print "Hi there, %d. Access granted."
            else
                print "Password incorrect. Access denied."
        else
            print "Sorry...I don't recognize you. Access denied."
```

However, I have been getting the error on the compiler:

```
$ valac evenmores.gs 
evenmores.gs:15.18-15.18: error: syntax error, expected `do' but got `<' with previous identifier
    for i=0 to i < users.length
                 ^
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

I also tried the for loop as suggested in [here](http://cheesehead-techblog.blogspot.com.au/2013/02/string-arrays-in-vala.html):

```
for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++)
```

With no avail. I would apreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: Look up syntax for the `for` statement.

Comment: That link is to C++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `var i = 1` and use `for i:int = 0 to (users.length - 1)`

There are a couple of points here:

- When the Genie `for` loop is used like this it is only to generate a number sequence. Be aware to generate a decreasing number sequence you need to use `downto` instead of `to`. A better way of iterating over an array is given below
- Genie is strongly typed and block scoped. When you first tried the `for` loop you may have got the error `` "The name 'i' does not exist in the context of `main'" `` and this is why you added `var i = 1`. You can, however, declare the variable as part of the `for` loop as shown above. Generally for the fundamental types such as `string` and `int` I prefer to make the type explicit, but you can use type inference as well. `for var i = 0 to (users.length -1)` will also work

To iterate over an array it is better to use the `for item in array` syntax. For your example this would look like:

```
[indent=4]
init
    users: array of string = {"Fred","John","Steve","Ann","Mary"}
    passwords: array of string = {"access","dog","12345","kids","qwerty"}

    print "Enter user name"
    usrname:string = stdin.read_line()
    print "Enter password"
    pwd:string = stdin.read_line()

    position:int = 0
    for var user in users
        if (user==usrname)
            if pwd == passwords[position]
                print "Hi there, %s. Access granted.", usrname
            else
                print "Password incorrect. Access denied."
        else
            print "Sorry...I don't recognize you. Access denied."
        position++
```

There is a fundamental problem with your code as you will see when you run it. I think a better solution would be to use a dictionary:

```
[indent=4]
init
    var access = new dict of string,string
    access[ "Fred" ] = "access"
    access[ "John" ] = "dog"
    access[ "Steve" ] = "12345"
    access[ "Ann" ] = "kids"
    access[ "Mary" ] = "qwerty"

    print "Enter user name"
    username:string = stdin.read_line()
    print "Enter password"
    pwd:string = stdin.read_line()

    if !(username in access.keys)
        print "Sorry...I don't recognize you. Access denied."
    else
        if pwd == access[ username ]      
            print "Hi there, %s. Access granted.", username
        else
            print "Password incorrect. Access denied."
```

The key points:

- A Genie dictionary needs `libgee` to work so you will need to install Gee and its development files. To build the program use `valac --pkg gee-0.8 my_example.gs`
- A dictionary is made  up of keys and values. To test that a user name is not present the `!` operator is used and the `in` keyword. Note also the `.keys`
- To access the values in the dictionary square brackets containing the key is used: `access[ username ]`

Answer (score 1):

```
init
    users: array of string = {"Fred","John","Steve","Ann","Mary"}
    passwords: array of string = {"access","dog","12345","kids","qwerty"}

    print "Enter user name"
    usrname:string = stdin.read_line()
    print "Enter password"
    pwd:string = stdin.read_line()  
    
    error:int = 0                   
    cont:int = 0        
    for var user in users
        if (user!=usrname)
            error++
            if error == (users.length)      
                print "No reconocido. Acceso denegado."             
        if (user==usrname)
            position:int = cont                 
            if pwd == passwords[position]               
                print "OK: Acceso Concedido."
            else                
                print "Password incorrecta."            
        cont++
```

Comment: You can find more exercises [here](https://lf-araujo.github.io/), and a Telegram group [here](https://telegram.me/joinchat/DP9KNQgnctdE8vULmtrQ3g).

Comment: Thanks, my wiki about Genie in Spanish: [Genie Doc](http://genie.webierta.skn1.com).

Comment: Duly noted. That is great! There are too few Genie learners now, join in the genie group as well and we can help each other there and grow the community.

Comment: I hope the Genie community will increase. Documentation is difficult to find. That's why I created that wiki.

In addition, I propose a logo for Genie, which can be seen at [logo](http://genie.webierta.skn1.com/wiki/logo). This logo represents a G as a VALA key to open C.

Comment: That is a fine idea, I also reached out to a designer before (for a logo)... I want to help you out with your site! How can I help?

Comment: Thank you. We continue to talk by email. Use the form of contact of my web: [Contacto](http://webierta.skn1.com/contacto)